# PHP while looping endlessly instead of iterating through MySQL table rows

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I can't figure out why this keeps breaking my page. Could someone take a look? Thanks!

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `col1` = 0"))) {
    echo $row['id'];
}
```

I've seen this type of while loop show up pretty regularly in google searches and just browsing through stackoverflow. I don't know why it isn't working for me.

How would I achieve the desired result? (Echo the id of each row where `col1 = 0`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `col1` = 0");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Obviously it is because you create new MySQL resource with every iteration and then  use it's first row.

Use something like

```
$res = mysql_query("...");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    echo $row['id']'
}
```

By the way, you do know that [mysql is deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), do you not?